# How to approximate a negative exponential distribution?

Tags: exponential-function, approximation-theory, queueing-theory

In [Hierarchical Web Caching Systems: Modeling, Design and Experimental Results](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1031903/) by  Hao Che, Ye Tung and Zhijun Wang, the authors used

$$
g(t) = \frac{\exp(- (t - \tau)/(T - \tau))}{T - \tau}
$$

to approximate

$$
f(t) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  ( - 1)^{n + 1}\frac{(t - n\tau )^{n - 1}}{T^n(n - 1)!}u(t - n\tau ), 
$$
where $u$ is the Heaviside function.

I did some numerical tests. Results show when $T/\tau$ is large enough, the value of these two functions is almost the same.

Is there any mathematical explanation?

Comment: What is function $u$?

Comment: Heaviside function

Comment: "the value of these two functions is almost the same" For which range of values of $t$?

Comment: In my experiment, when $t$ is five times larger than $tau$, the curves of these two functions almost coincide.